# How can I get the value of a radio button when the page is posted with mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a group of radiobutton like that;

`<input type="radio" name="@DataValue1" value="@DataValueA"> 
<input type="radio" name="@DataValue2" value="@DataValueB">`

I could not get the name and/or value of the selected radio button after a post. 
I used everything in formcollection but I can only see the details of the submit button.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult prepareOpelData(FormCollection frm1)
    {


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to define parameters with same name in the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult prepareOpelData(string dataValue1, string dataValue2)
{
}
```

You can also define a model with same properties and MVC will bind it for you.

```
class PostModel
{
    public string DataValue1 {get; set;}
    public string DataValue2 {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult prepareOpelData(PostModel model)
{
    var dataValue1 = model.DataValue1;
    ....
}
```

Have a read how [Model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) works.

Comment: Thanks Andrii Litvinov,,